# iOS: AppIntent parameter supporting multiple types of data?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, appintents

I currently have 3 AppIntents that each support different kinds of input data. I'd prefer to have a single AppIntent that can receive anything - similar to the `AirDrop` shortcut action.

I know I can create an `AppEntity` with custom data, but I'm looking for input from a previous action/variable, not something defined within my app, so it doesn't seem applicable.

`AppEnum` doesn't work, because it requires a static display representation.

I've tried `Any`, `AnyObject`, and `enum` to no success.

Is this possible?

Comment: I noticed that there are shortcuts in twitter and facebook that can pass in text, images, urls three different kinds of input data at the same time, but I can't figure out how they do it.
Maybe they didn't use AppIntents?

Comment: @Eriice I think they must be using the previous way of making Intents.

Comment: Yes, I share the same sentiment. Particularly noticeable was the comparison with the WWDC 2021 video, where they initially introduced Intent as 'custom intent'. Yet, in the [2023 AppIntent video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10168/), the focus shifted to converting these custom intents into AppIntent. However, I encountered difficulties when attempting to use the 2021 intent to create multiple types for a single input, like Twitter, but unfortunately, I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to emulate Twitter by passing an image to a shortcut, which would then trigger a sheet to pop up. However, with the latest AppIntent, it seems that the approach is to use the 'openAppWhenRun' parameter to open the application. Interestingly, I noticed that Twitter's shortcut doesn't have this parameter, yet it still successfully opens a sheet. And this 'sheet' not like open by Twitter app but as a single page or extension page open by shortcut.